# Why is my cast failing when i cast to BRGameState? I have put the object as Get Game State, yet the cast still fails

Tags: casting, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

[See the function here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YnFf.png)
I think that BRGameState is correct, so is Get Game State as the object node, yet it still fails and I have no clue why.

Comment: Stating the obvious - it's probably not the active game state.

Comment: You should try to see what type the game state actually has when the cast fails. Is it null? Is it a different class?